# Filtering a formatted date column of a Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this `DateTime` column in my grid:

```
column.Bound(c => c.PaymentMonth).ClientTemplate("#= PaymentMonthString #")
            .Filterable(filterable => filterable
            .Operators(op => op.ForDate(d => d.Clear().IsEqualTo("Equals")))
            .Extra(false).UI("dateFilter"));
```

The `PaymentMonthString` is a read-only string property that returns the `PaymentMonth` in `"MMMM yyyy"` format.

Here's the `dateFilter` function for the custom filter UI:

```
<script>
    function dateFilter(e) {
        e.kendoDatePicker({
            format: "MMMM yyyy",
            depth: "year",
            start: "year"
        });
    }
</script>
```

But, the filter never works, because when you select a date from the filter menu, the current day is used by default as the day part of the date. For example, if you choose March 2016 on 3/14/2016, the date will be 3/14/2016. But, when I filter on a `"MMMM yyyy"` column, I don't care about the day. All the dates in March 2016 should be included. How do I make that work?

Comment: you need to use custom filter to achieve your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured how to get this to work. In the change event of the date-picker in the filter UI, we can filter the grid's data-source for all the dates that are greater than or equal to the first day of the selected month and are less than or equal to the last they of that month. Here's the updated code for the `dateFilter` function:

```
<script>
    function dateFilter(e) {
        e.removeAttr("data-bind");
        e.kendoDatePicker({
            format: "MMMM yyyy",
            depth: "year",
            start: "year",
            change: function () {
                var ds = $("#grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource;
                var filter = {
                    "logic": "and",
                    "filters": [
                      {
                          "field": "PaymentMonth",
                          "operator": "gte",
                          "value": new Date(this.value().getFullYear(), this.value().getMonth(), 0)
                      },
                      {
                          "field": "PaymentMonth",
                          "operator": "lte",
                          "value": new Date(this.value().getFullYear(), this.value().getMonth() + 1, 0)
                      }
                    ]
                };
                ds.filter(filter);
                this.element.closest("form").data().kendoPopup.close();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @thepirat000, no, it doesn't. In that case, the year will be incremented by one, and the month will become January.